# c does not follow the program operation procedure

Tags: c, fopen

summary : system("clear"); isn't working well.

I'm using gcc, ubuntu 18.04 LTS version for c programming.

what I intended was "read each words and print from two text files. After finish read file, delay 3 seconds and erase terminal"

so I was make two text files, and using system("clear"); to erase terminal.

here is whole code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void printFiles(char *file1,char *file2,char *change1, char *change2){
  FILE *f;
  char *text = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
  f=fopen(file1,"r");

  system("clear");
  //while(!feof(f)){
  while(EOF!=fscanf(f,"%s",text)){
    //fscanf(f,"%s", text);
    printf("%s ",text);
    //usleep(20000);
  }
  //sleep(3);

  fclose(f);
  printf("\n");
  //all comment problems are appear here. and if I give delay, such as usleep() or sleep, delay also appear here. Not appear each wrote part.

  f=fopen(file2,"r");
  //while(!feof(f)){
  while(EOF!=fscanf(f,"%s",text)){
    if(strcmp(text,"**,")==0){
      strcpy(text,change1);
      strcat(text,",");
    }

    else if(strcmp(text,"**")==0){
      strcpy(text,change1);
    }
    else if(strcmp(text,"##.")==0){
      strcpy(text,change2);
      strcat(text,".");
    }
    else if(strcmp(text,"##,")==0){
      strcpy(text,change2);
      strcat(text,",");
    }
    printf("%s ",text);
    //usleep(200000);
  }
  fclose(f);
  free(text);
  sleep(3); //here is problem. This part works in the above commented part "//all comment problems are appear here."
  system("clear"); //here is problem. This part works in the above commented part "//all comment problems are appear here."
}


int main(){
  char file1[100] = "./file1.txt";
  char file2[100] = "./file2.txt";
  char change1[100]="text1";
  char change2[100]="text2";
  printFiles(file1,file2,change1,change2);
  return 0;
}
```

I'm very sorry, files and variables names are changed because of policy. Also, file contents also can not upload.

I can't find which part makes break Procedure-oriented programming. I think that was compiler error, because using one file read and `system(clear);` works well.

I also make two point variables, such as 'FILE *f1; FILE *f2;  f1=fopen(file1); f2=fopen(file2)...`, but same result occur.

Is it compiler error? If it is, what should I do for fix these problem? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not able to understand the actual issue you have. Can you clarify?

Comment: using gcc version : gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: @yang What this comment is supposed to clarify?

Comment: 'system("clear");' is not act when function ended, act 'fclose()';

Comment: sorry, i will fix comment

Comment: You should check the return value of `fopen`

Comment: Are you saying that `system("clear")` does not seem to work?

Comment: You should use `strscpy` (you may have to code it yourself) unless you know for sure a lot of things about the strings being used by `strcpy`. If you don't want to use `strscpy`, think at least of using `strlcpy` (from libbsd) or `strncpy` (standard)

Comment: The same with `strcat` as with `strcpy`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes. It looks like not working well

Comment: There's a macro in `<stdio.h>` called `FILENAME_MAX`. You should use that instead of the magic number `100`

Comment: In `malloc`, you should use `sizeof(*text)` instead of `sizeof(char)` for the (unlikely) case that you change the data type of `text`.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito yes, that was prototype for the whole code. After fix `system("clear");` error, then I will fix it. thanks.

Comment: That's probably just buffering. Do `fflush(stdout);` before you sleep.

Comment: I'm almost sure you're overflowing `text`. Use a larger buffer (`BUFSIZ` should be your standard always, unless you specifically need something bigger, or have specific low memory requirements), and check the functions I told you to check for buffer overflow

Comment: @Yang `system("clear")` can not fail (unless some weird conditions).  Probably there is a buffer overflow causing undefined behaviour, and that can manifest as anything, making you think `clear` is failing.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for your help. answer was erase buffer after printf();

Comment: Thanks for everyone. 
The answer is make code like `while(EOF!=fscanf(f,"%s",text)){
    //fscanf(f,"%s", text);
    printf("%s ",text);
    fflush(stdout);
    usleep(80000);
  }`

Comment: @Yang You should post your answer as an answer. BTW, that's not "erasing" the buffer, but flushing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution for **delay**.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void delay(double seconds)
{
    const time_t start = time(NULL);
    time_t current;

    do
    {
        time(&current);
    } while(difftime(current, start) < seconds);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Just waiting...\n");
    delay(3);
    printf("...oh man, waiting for so long...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Following solution is pretty quite the same of previous one but with a **clear terminal** solution.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
    #define CLEAR_SCREEN system ("cls");
#else
    #define CLEAR_SCREEN puts("\x1b[H\x1b[2J");
#endif

void delay(double seconds)
{
    const time_t start = time(NULL);
    time_t current;

    do
    {
        time(&current);
    } while(difftime(current, start) < seconds);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Just waiting...\n");
    delay(2); //seconds
    printf("...oh man, waiting for so long...\n");
    delay(1);
    CLEAR_SCREEN
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void printFiles(char *file1,char *file2,char *change1, char *change2){
  FILE *f;
  char *text = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
  f=fopen(file1,"r");

  system("clear");
  //while(!feof(f)){
  while(EOF!=fscanf(f,"%s",text)){
    //fscanf(f,"%s", text);
    printf("%s ",text);
    fflush(stdout);
    //usleep(20000);
  }
  //sleep(3);

  fclose(f);
  printf("\n");
  //all comment problems are appear here. and if I give delay, such as usleep() or sleep, delay also appear here. Not appear each wrote part.

  f=fopen(file2,"r");
  //while(!feof(f)){
  while(EOF!=fscanf(f,"%s",text)){
    if(strcmp(text,"**,")==0){
      strcpy(text,change1);
      strcat(text,",");
    }

    else if(strcmp(text,"**")==0){
      strcpy(text,change1);
    }
    else if(strcmp(text,"##.")==0){
      strcpy(text,change2);
      strcat(text,".");
    }
    else if(strcmp(text,"##,")==0){
      strcpy(text,change2);
      strcat(text,",");
    }
    printf("%s ",text);
    fflush(stdout);// The answer. 
    //usleep(200000);
  }
  fclose(f);
  free(text);
  sleep(3); //here is problem. This part works in the above commented part "//all comment problems are appear here."
  system("clear"); //here is problem. This part works in the above commented part "//all comment problems are appear here."
}


int main(){
  char file1[100] = "./file1.txt";
  char file2[100] = "./file2.txt";
  char change1[100]="text1";
  char change2[100]="text2";
  printFiles(file1,file2,change1,change2);
  return 0;
}
```

Hint for 
`That's probably just buffering. Do fflush(stdout); before you sleep. – melpomene`
Thanks.